# AG Grid background cell colour change based on another property that is not a column

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to set a background colour of a column cell based on a value of the object property that is not a column. The value of the property is changed dynamically based on another event so this is the flow

```
event fires -> changes data -> changes value of the row data in grid -> which should change the background of the column.
```

It is working but only when I scroll the rows in the grid up/down or left/right. It seems like scrolls forces to refresh cells and then it shows the colour but not instantly.

This is my column def for that column on which I want background-colour set

```
 {
        headerName: 'TestColumn 1',
        field: 'testColumn1',
        sortable: false,
        cellClass: ({ data }: CellClassParams) =>
            ['ag-editable', 'ag-align-center', BreachStatusCellClassType[data?.testColumn2]],

    }
```

As you can see, the above formatting is based on another property "testColumn2" which is not a columns in the grid.

The background is set but not instantly and needs refreshing. I have got it working instantly by force refreshing the cells manually like below. However, that means refreshing all cells every time which is not what I want.

```
this.agGrid.api.refreshCells({ force: true })
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `refreshCells` is the correct way to go. If you only want to specific rows or columns, you can specify the `columns` or `rowNodes` params.

See documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/view-refresh/#refresh-cells).